# Extracting data and Comparing Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have two tables in Access 2003, these tables hold model numbers and account numbers, with the serial number being the primary key. How could I go about comparing a the same serial number in the two tables and see what changed?

For example:

[image]

Lets say row 2 is from TableA and Row 3 is from TableB, how would I extract a row from one table (row 2) and compare it to the same primary key in a different table (row 3).

Comment: And what should be the result of the compare?

Comment: It would just overwrite the data in TableA and add Change in my update_type column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will show you which `[Serial Number]` values have different values for `[Model Number]` and/or `[Account Number]`.

```sql
SELECT
    a.[Serial Number],
    a.[Model Number] AS model_number_a,
    b.[Model Number] AS model_number_b,
    a.[Account Number] AS account_number_a,
    b.[Account Number] AS account_number_b
FROM
    TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN TableB AS b
    ON a.[Serial Number] = b.[Serial Number]
WHERE
       a.[Model Number] <> b.[Model Number]
    OR a.[Account Number] <> b.[Account Number];
```

Note that query will only examine `[Serial Number]` values which are present in both tables.  If you also want to return rows where a `TableA.[Serial Number]` does not exist in `TableB`, change the join to `LEFT JOIN`.

If the `[Model Number]` and/or `[Account Number]` can contain Nulls, the comparisons will be more challenging.  If you will be running the query from within an Access application session, you can use `Nz()` to cope with Nulls.

```sql
WHERE Nz(a.[Model Number], '') <> Nz(b.[Model Number], '')
```

If you need to run the query from outside Access, use an `IIf()` expression.

```sql
WHERE
    IIf(a.[Model Number] Is Null, '', a.[Model Number])
    <>
    IIf(b.[Model Number] Is Null, '', b.[Model Number])
```